# Display price in cart block with total

Tags: cart

Hi i need display in cart with total block also different price: display price in cart without tax and display price in cart with tax - where and what i need modify for display prices, prices should be in different fow and display always

Thanks

Comment: In the backend under System > Config > Taxes you can configure to show all this afaik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System > configuration > Sales > Shopping Cart Display Settings

[image: Shopping Cart Display Settings]

Answer (score 0):

yes right, but i need display this only here:

[image]

this block after table, next setting System > configuration > Sales > Shopping Cart Display Settings modify my cart table only

Need display: Shipping and Grand Total without TAX